# MDX: Aggregate [Date].[Calendar].[Quarter] level to create new [Date].[Calendar].[Semi Annual] Level

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a Date Dimension that has Month Hierarchy

```
Year -> Quarter -> Month -> Day -> Hour
```

I have two measures. Measure_A (Aggregation is Max), Measure_B (Aggregation is SUM)

I need to Multiply Measure_A by 24 on "Day" level then I need to SUM it Semi Annually.

Is it possible to create a new hierarchy by just using an MDX query? Below is the output that i am trying to achieve

```
Year | CY H1 | Measure_C | Measure_B
```

Where: `Measure_C` is the SUM of (Measure_A * 24) from January 1 to June 30, and `CY H1` will be the new level.

I don't have any problem with Measure_B because its aggregation is SUM. Only with Measure_A beacause the aggregation is Max.

Is this possible to achieve without altering the cube, just do an MDX? Thanks.

```
Updated:
```

This is my query and output as of the moment,

Query:

```
With
  MEMBER [Measures].[Measure_C] AS
    SUM (   Descendants ( [Date].[Date Calendar],  [Date].[Date Calendar].[Day]), [Measures].[Measure_A] * 24 )
    , Format_String = "#,##0"

Select 
  {
    [Measures].[Measure_C]
  } ON Columns,
  NON Empty
  {
    [Date].[Date Calendar].[Quarter].ALLMEMBERS
  } ON Rows
From [Cube]
```

Output:

```
+------+---------+-----------+
| Year | Quarter | Measure_C |
+------+---------+-----------+
| 2011 | Q1      |        12 |
| 2011 | Q2      |        45 |
| 2011 | Q3      |        12 |
| 2011 | Q4      |        25 |
+------+---------+-----------+
```

What I am trying to do is to merge Q1 and Q2 to get Calendar Semester for the first half (CY H1)

Required output:

```
+------+---------+-----------+
| Year | Half Yr | Measure_C |
+------+---------+-----------+
| 2011 | CY H1   |        57 |
| 2011 | CY H2   |        37 |
+------+---------+-----------+
```

Please note that we don't have a natural Hierarchy for `CY H1`. But according to the comment below, this is not possible using mdx alone.

By the way, I am doing this for reporting services so I guess I will just do the magic in the presentation layer since this is not achievable using MDX query alone. :)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `Year | CY H1 | Measure_C | Measure_B`. Is this meant to be e. g. the column header? This is not possibly in MDX. You can only have members of the same hierarchy on the same level of the column headers.

Comment: Yes you are right about the column headers, I just thought if it is possible to do in mdx. thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your year 2011 is named `[Date].[Date Calendar].[2011]`, then you can add calculated members as children of it like this:

```
With
  MEMBER [Measures].[Measure_C] AS
    Aggregate ( Descendants ( [Date].[Date Calendar],  [Date].[Date Calendar].[Day]),
                [Measures].[Measure_A] * 24 
              )
    , Format_String = "#,##0"
  MEMBER [Date].[Date Calendar].[2011].[CY H1] AS
    Aggregate({ [Date].[Date Calendar].[Q1], [Date].[Date Calendar].[Q2] })
  MEMBER [Date].[Date Calendar].[2011].[CY H2] AS
    Aggregate({ [Date].[Date Calendar].[Q3], [Date].[Date Calendar].[Q4] })

Select 
  {
    [Measures].[Measure_C]
  } ON Columns,
  NON Empty
  {
    [Date].[Date Calendar].[2011].[CY H1],
    [Date].[Date Calendar].[2011].[CY H2]
  } ON Rows
From [Cube]
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I just got back from vacation. Your solution actually works for other measures that has SUM as its aggregation, but this does not work with Measure_A that is aggregate as MAX. Anyway thanks for your answer, I can also use this solution to some of the templates I am working on. :)

Comment: @ggarcia As you were using `SUM` in your question, I was assuming all your measures are summable. If some are not, you can use `Aggregate` instead of `Sum`. This will use the aggregation configured for each measure. I just edited my answer to take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try defining something like

```
With Member [Measures].[Measure C] as Sum( [Date].[2014].[1].[1].[1] : [Date].[2014].[2].[6].[30] ), [Measures].[Measure A] ) * 24
```

Alternatively, you can define it in a more flexible way, such as

Member [Measures].[Measure C pre] as Sum( Descendants( [Date].CurrentMember, [Date].[Day] ), [Measures].[Measure A] ),

which is the sum of the max of each day, but this is only valid for Date members that exist in the dimension (not calculated members). You will then need to explicitly calculate the aggregation using the same set of months or quarters you are using in your Rows clause.